# how to test whether a trigger is fired in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-3

I am using doctrine2 in Codeigniter 3.  I have a trigger for order table where I want to automatically dump data after I inserted some data in order_replica table. This is my trigger which is not working and I do not know how to test trigger. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
DELIMITER @@
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_insert_order_replica;
@@
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_order_replica` AFTER INSERT ON `order_replica`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO order (replica_id) VALUES (NEW.id);
END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I don't think this compiles you are using an unescaped reserved word (order).

Comment: This name is only an example..I used different name,i.e., com_order

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I just import this code and then insert some data to order_replica table which generate record to order table